# PHP object-oriented Inheritance - accessing parent's property

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I need to access a property of a parent inside a function of the child class. A static variable can accessed with `parent::` but  how can I access a non-static parent variable when the child class has a variable with the same name?

```
class My_parent{
  $name = "Praeep";
}

class My_child extends My_parent {
  $name ="Nadeesha";

  function show_name() {
    // need to access $name of the parent just referring the parent variable 
  }
}
```

Comment: _“but how can I access a non-static parent variable when the child class has a variable with the same name”_ – how does that requirement even make sense? If the child class has a (non-static) variable with the same name, that means you have _overwritten_ it …

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add a construct function to your parent class and define your variable inside this function.

```
class My_parent{
  public $name;
  public function __construct(){
    $this->name= "Praeep";
  }
}
```

If your child class has a construct function too, you need to invoke the parents construct function manually. However a class doesn't have to have a construct function so I commented it out for simplicity.

```
class My_child extends My_parent {
  // public function __construct(){
  //   parent::__construct();
  // }
  public function show_name(){
    echo $this->name;
  }
}

$c=new My_child();
$c->show_name();
```

EDIT:

well in fact you don't need the construct function in the parent class.

```
class My_parent{
  public $name= "Praeep";
}

class My_child extends My_parent {

  public function show_name(){
    echo $this->name;
  }
}

$c=new My_child();
$c->show_name();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it is no problem to access it via method like what you mentioned. but i want to need that is there are direct way without using constructors or any methods to call it such as in CLASS VARIABLES in which class can refer its own by using SELF:: whereas the parent using PARENT::

Comment: no that is not possible because you need to return the object.

Comment: This breaks encapsulation pretty bad. It should be either private with a proper getter or protected. This is bad practice, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can either declare the variable in the parent class with a `protected` modifier or provide a getter. The getter approach would be prefered to ensure encapsulation.

```
class My_parent{
  private $name = "Praeep";
  public function getName() {
      return $this->name;
  }
}

class My_child extends My_parent {
  public function show_name() {
    echo $this->getName(); 
  }
}
```

If you also want the property to be mutable consider providing a setter as well.